# might in reported speech

Tags: spoken-english, reported-speech

Direct speech:"You might post **these** for me",he said.

Indirect speech(book answer): He requested me to post **them** for him.

I have two doubt here. first can we use **might as request** and second doubt is that i think there should be **those** instead of **them**. Because we change **these** into change **those** while converting it into indirect sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, "might" is used as a request only if the person being asked to perform the request has already volunteered.

> I know you're very busy. Is there anything I can do to help?
>   -- You might post these letters for me, if you're going to be near the post office.

With regard to your second question about them/those: there is no *requirement* to change *them* to *those*. The following are all idiomatic:

> Why are you holding perfumed letters addressed to Mary's boyfriend?
>   --Oh, Mary is busy, and has asked me to mail them.
>   --Oh, Mary is busy, and has asked me to mail these.
>   --Oh, Mary is busy, and has asked me to mail those.
>
> Why were you holding perfumed letters addressed to Mary's boyfriend?
>   --Oh, Mary was busy, and asked me to mail them.
>   --Oh, Mary was busy, and asked me to mail those.

Comment: OK i agree with you. But in multiple choice question in exam if we have to choose one answer then what would we choose, them or those?

Comment: Sorry, advice on test-taking is not what this site is about.